# How to: Join Multiple Tables and Insert Desired Columns Into One MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, sql-insert

I have a few tables I'm trying to join into a single table using 4 joins.

The tables are:

**vehicle**

```
vehicleId
make
model
year
cylinders
displacement
drive
engid
eng_dscr
trany
mpgHighway
mpgCity
fuelCostAnnual
fuelType
fuelType1
vClass
```

**vehicledrive**

```
driveId
driveName
```

**vehiclefueltype**

```
fuelId
fuelName
```

**vehiclemake**

```
makeId
makeName
```

**vehiclemodel**

```
modelId
modelName
```

I have a new table, **vehiclenormal**, which normalizes the vehicle table, and uses the other 3 tables as look-ups for repetitive values.

So far, all I have is the statement that joins all the tables:

```
select vehicle.*, vehicledrive.*, vehiclefueltype.*, vehiclemake.*, vehiclemodel.*
from vehicle

join vehicledrive
on vehicle.drive = vehicledrive.driveName

join vehiclefueltype
on vehicle.fueltype = vehiclefueltype.fuelname

join vehiclemake
on vehicle.make = vehiclemake.makename

join vehiclemodel
on vehicle.model = vehiclemodel.modelname

order by vehicle.vehicleid
```

My problem is that I don't know how to add the insert statement. I know that I can use an insert into ... select, but how do I specify what columns and rows I want to insert based on the result of the joins?

Edit: Okay, I've found out how to select only the data I want to insert, and I tried the following query:

```
insert into vehiclenormal (makeid, modelid, year, cylinders, driveid, mpghighway, mpgcity, fueltypeid)
(select makeid, modelid, year, cylinders, driveid, mpghighway, mpgcity, fuelid
from vehicle
join vehicledrive on vehicledrive.driveName = vehicle.drive
join vehiclefueltype on vehiclefueltype.fuelName = vehicle.fueltype
join vehiclemake on vehiclemake.makeName = vehicle.make
join vehiclemodel on vehiclemodel.modelname = vehicle.model);
```

But HeidiSQL is saying there were over 21,000 errors. Why isn't it inserting the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use INSERT INTO syntax:

```
insert into vehiclenormal
    (makeid, modelid, year, driveName, fuelName, makeName, modelName)
    select d.makeId, e.modelId, a.year, b.driveName, c.fuelName, d.makeName, e.modelName
    from vehicle a
      join vehicledrive b on a.drive = b.driveName
      join vehiclefueltype c on a.fueltype = c.fuelName
      join vehiclemake d on a.make = d.makeName
      join vehiclemodel e on a.model = e.modelName;
```

Comment: I actually just tried the insert into, but I got nothing but warnings. I just edited my original post.

Comment: I did not include all columns in vehicle in the example, but hope you get the idea anyway...

Comment: The significance of the a,b,c,d,e is the table name, right? If so, why does one need to be so explicit?

Comment: Edited with example of how to get makeId and modelId from the right table.. Please make sure the field names are capitalized in the right places.

Comment: Yes, a, b, c etc are just short aliases for the tables. You could instead use the real table names directly, like: `vehiclemake.makeId, vehiclemodel.modelId, vehicle.year` You have to be explicit in expressing from what table you want to get what field...

Comment: Are the table names needed though?

Comment: If you have identical field names in any of the included tables, then Yes, you always have to specify the tables names. In your case, you seem to have no duplicate names included, but it is a good practice to always specify the table names, and I actually do not know if it works without them. Let me know if this solution works for you.

Comment: I'm still getting the error after specifying all the table names. It's: Data truncated for column 'mpgHighway' at row 1. What would this mean?

Comment: Make sure the data types in the new table matches the data type in the field you are trying to insert from.... If you have a char(100) in the source table, and char(50) in the new, then your data will be truncated.

Comment: I totally forgot MySQL did that. Thank you. It worked.